# Why so much time does the function Color.FromValues

Tags: c#, performance, colors, color-profile, color-management

Wrote a little test for color conversion to the use of ICC profiles.
Conversion function works 1,000 times slower!

What's the problem?

```
    Uri iccUri = new Uri("C:\\temp\\AdobeRGB1998.icc");
    private Color AdobeColor(int r, int g, int b)
    {
        float[] colorValues = new float[3];
        colorValues[0] = (float)r / 255.0f;
        colorValues[1] = (float)g/255.0f;
        colorValues[2] = (float)b/255.0f;
        return Color.FromValues(colorValues,iccUri);
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
        {
            Color a = AdobeColor(n, n, n);//very very slow
            //Color a = Color.FromRgb((byte)n, (byte)n, (byte)n);//very fast

        }

        sw.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts;
        ts = sw.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine("result: {0}\n", ts.Seconds);
    }
```

Comment: how did you measure the relative speeds? I see no timing code...

Comment: Each call to this function is performed in seconds!

Comment: Why wouldn't it be slower? You are doing file IO and color profile mapping vs. a simple struct initialization.

Comment: Not in the same 1000 times longer!
One call takes me about 1.5 seconds.

Comment: I downloaded the ICC from Adobe and tried your code. It seems to be able to run the Test in about 40 milliseconds. Is that not good enough ?

Comment: I checked on a different profile.
The result is a long one.
Perhaps some sort of a problem in my system?
My test result is 12 seconds (I7 CPU)

Comment: 12 seconds sounds like an awful lot. How large if the ICC file you are using ? Are you sure it is not corrupted (try re-downloading it, perhaps) ?

Comment: 560 bytes 
As I already wrote. I tried the other profile (sRGB) the result is the same

Answer (score 1):

Two possible explanations:

- `Color.FromValues` might need to lookup the ICC profile for each call, which is expensive (At least, orders of magnitude more expensive than creating a new simple Color object)
- If `Color.FromValues` caches the profile, there might be a problem with your particular profile, causing the caching to not work.

Now, since `FromValues` requires disk access, and `FromRgb` is a very simple arithmetic operation followed by the creation of a single `Color` object, `FromValues` IS going to be orders of magnitude slower. I tried a simple benchmark and got:

```
FromValues 37.6278 ms
FromRgb     0.0029 ms
```

So it seems that FromValues is about 10000 times slower than FromRgb, at least on my system.

Comment: In that it took all the time? :)

Comment: 10 iterations of FromValues takes 38 milliseconds, and the same 10 iterations of FromRgb took 0.0029 ms, with a simple benchmark based on your code.

Comment: I have 1.5 seconds on every call

Comment: Did you try it on another machine to verify ?

Comment: While not tested. Tomorrow check.

Comment: Or if you have another disk, try moving the file there. I checked in source, and there seems to be no internal caching of the profile, so it will hit the disk each time - if the disk is slow or faulty, this might be the problem. Anyways, I don't think I can help much more :-)